# Why does foreachRDD not populate DataFrame with new content using StreamingContext.textFileStream?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

My problem is that, as I change my code into streaming mode and put my data frame into the foreach loop, the data frame shows empty table! I does't fill! I also can not put it into assembler.transform(). The error is:

```
Error:(38, 40) not enough arguments for method map: (mapFunc: String => U)(implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[U])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[U].
Unspecified value parameter mapFunc.
      val dataFrame = Train_DStream.map()
```

My train.csv file is like below:
[image]
Please help me. 
Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.{LabeledPoint, StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.util.Try

/**
  * Created by saeedtkh on 5/22/17.
  */
object ML_Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("HdfsWordCount")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    // Create the context
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("column0", StringType, true),
      StructField("column1", StringType, true),
      StructField("column2", StringType, true)))

      //val Test_DStream = ssc.textFileStream("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/train.csv").map(LabeledPoint.parse)
      val Train_DStream = ssc.textFileStream("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/train.csv")
      val DStream =Train_DStream.map(line => line.split(">")).map(array => {
      val first = Try(array(0).trim.split(" ")(0)) getOrElse ""
      val second = Try(array(1).trim.split(" ")(6)) getOrElse ""
      val third = Try(array(2).trim.split(" ")(0).replace(":", "")) getOrElse ""
      Row.fromSeq(Seq(first, second, third))
    })

      DStream.foreachRDD { Test_DStream =>
      val dataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Test_DStream, customSchema)
      dataFrame.groupBy("column1", "column2").count().show()

      val numFeatures = 3
      val model = new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD()
          .setInitialWeights(Vectors.zeros(numFeatures))

      val featureCol = Array("column1", "column2")
      val assembler=new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(featureCol).setOutputCol("features")
      dataFrame.show()
      val df_new=assembler.transform(dataFrame)

    }

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the Spark version?

Comment: How does `/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/train.csv` look like? Is this a directory or file? What do you get from `dataFrame.show()`?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: I use 2.11.2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145139/discussion-between-jacek-laskowski-and-saeed-talaee).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My *guess* is that all the files under `/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/train.csv` directory have already been processed and so there are no files left and hence the DataFrame is empty.

Please note that the sole input parameter for [StreamingContext.textFileStream](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@textFileStream(directory:String):org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[String]) is a directory not a file.

> **textFileStream(directory: String): DStream[String]** Create an input stream that monitors a Hadoop-compatible filesystem for new files and reads them as text files

Please also note that once a file has ever been processed in a Spark Streaming application, this file should **not** be changed (or appended to) since the file has already been marked as processed and Spark Streaming will ignore any modifications.

Quoting the official documentation of Spark Streaming in [Basic Sources](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-sources):

> Spark Streaming will monitor the directory `dataDirectory` and process any files created in that directory (files written in nested directories not supported). 
>   Note that
>
> - The files must have the same data format.
> - The files must be created in the dataDirectory by atomically moving or renaming them into the data directory.
> - Once moved, the files must not be changed. So if the files are being continuously appended, the new data will not be read.
>
> For simple text files, there is an easier method `streamingContext.textFileStream(dataDirectory)`. And file streams do not require running a receiver, hence does not require allocating cores.

---

Please also replace `setMaster("local")` with `setMaster("local[*]")` to make sure your Spark Streaming application will have enough threads to process incoming data (you have to have at least 2 threads).

Comment: So why transform() dose't work with my data frame? It gives me an error. The error is in question.

Comment: Very useful and complete answer!