# pyspark textFileStreaming can not detect txt file while textFile works

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

**To explain my question is different:** This question is different from the marked one. First, the input parameter is already a directory(which is correct but the marked question is wrong). Second, I copied the txt file to the directory during streaming running to simulate the new txt file arriving(So new files are generated instead of same files existing in this directory)

**My questionis below**

---

I have a directory and txt file `/tmp/a.txt`, the contents in file is

```
aaa
bbb
```

I use pyspark and manually copy this file in same directory, continuously (during streaming running the files are created at the same time)

```
def count(x):
    if x.isEmpty:
        print("empty")
        return
    print(x.count())

sc = SparkContext()
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)
ssc.textFileStream("/tmp/").foreachRDD(count)
```

The output shows the RDD is empty

However I use

```
c = sc.textFile("/tmp/").count()
print(c)
```

it shows c is 2 (consistent with the txt file contents)

Why streaming does not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does foreachRDD not populate DataFrame with new content using StreamingContext.textFileStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183471/why-does-foreachrdd-not-populate-dataframe-with-new-content-using-streamingconte)

Comment: @user10938362 not duplicate, explanation has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution in scala (still can not pick up new files in python)

First, the `sc.textFile` and `sc.textFileStream` takes same paramter, which is a directory name. So above code is right.

However, the difference is, it's Okay for `sc.textFile` to pick up the files if the directory exists (and it must exist otherwise `InvalidInputException` would be raised), but in streaming mode `sc.textFileStream` (local file system), it demands that the directory does not exist and created by streaming program, otherwise the new files could not be picked up (seems to be a bug, only exists in local file system, in HDFS seems to work well according to others experience).

What's more, from some others experience they say that if you delete the directory and re-run the program, the recycle bin must also be emptied.

---

However, in python this issue still exists, and during no files exist in the directory, scala program would just print `0` but python program would raise warning of

```
WARN FileInputDStream:87 - Error finding new files 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is my code in python and scala, the way of writing new files are same so I do not post it here

**python code:**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext()    
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)
    ssc.textFileStream(path).foreachRDD(lambda x: print(x.count()))
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

**scala code:**

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {  
  val sc = new SparkContext()
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(3))
  ssc.textFileStream(params.inputPath).foreachRDD { x =>
    print(x.count())
  }
  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pick up new lines being appended to the  `/tmp/a.txt` file or are you trying to pick up new files being added to the `tmp` directory?

If its the latter try replacing your last line with this

`ssc.textFileStream("/tmp/*").foreachRDD(count)`

Comment: picking up new files. Since I just copy `a.txt` in the same directory, `a.txt` does not change but there are `a(1).txt, a(2).txt, etc.` generated

Comment: I would try, but as usual the parameter of `sc.textFile` seems to be a directory and `sc.textFileStream` seems to be the same

Comment: Instead of copying and pasting the file try moving them in from another directory and with a different name.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your methods above but the issue still remains. After some discussion I have found a solution to go through it and I have posted it already